# Is it worth leaving the hotel in Verona on January 1st?

Tags: italy, public-holidays

January 1st is an official holiday in Italy and I wonder if there are some museums, touristic sites, shops or restaurants open on that day. I am not looking for a particular list but going to make my plans according to the availability of such touristic attractions on that day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though I have not been there, I would say the best thing in Verona is neither museums, shops nor restaurants, it is walking around in the city and enjoying the beautiful architecture. I am sure you can spend at least a day strolling around.

Answer (score 6):

There were plenty of restaurants and cafes open on that day. Many churches were open and available to visit. Giardino Giusti was also open. Casa di Giuletta was closed though.